# SQLQuery calling custom function twice with different parameters only executed first time

Tags: hibernate, postgresql

I have a custom function which I execute more than once with different parameters in a query like so:

```
select
    my_function(input.pt, false),
    my_function(input.pt, true)
from (select st_geomfromewkt('SRID=1;POINT(151.2836 -33.7859484007395)') as pt) as input;
```

When run outside of java/hibernate this executes just fine returning two different values:

```
1, 2
```

However, when I call exactly the same query with exactly the same parameters via a hibernate SQLQuery I get the first result twice:

```
SQLQuery qry = session.createSQLQuery("SELECT "//
    + " my_function(input.pt, false)," //
    + " my_function(input.pt, true)" //
    + " FROM (SELECT st_geomfromewkt(:point) AS pt) AS input;");
qry.setString("point", "SRID=1;POINT(151.2836 -33.7859484007395)");
Object[] result = (Object[]) qry.uniqueResult();
```

result:

```
[1, 1]
```

I have double checked that i am running against the same db and schema.

any ideas?

Comment: tometzky i will try your suggestion (logging) soon, however just a side note, i've tested that if i switch the function calls around (ie true, then false) i always get the result of the first call twice when via hibernate (2,2).

Answer (score 1):

As a superuser (`postgres` by default) run this:

```
set log_statement='all';
```

Then run your hibernate SQLQuery. You'll see in Postgres log file what is the command issued to a database. Maybe this would help you.

Don't forget to `set log_statement='none';` back after testing as logging all statements would be slow.

Apart from this there can be something wrong with your function — we can't help without it's definition.